# Paypal html form - how to direct to enhanced checkout page

Tags: paypal

I have a paypal website standard payments html form for donations that prepolates some of the form data (like name, address, telephone) and sends these to the **Classic** paypal check-out page.

The form start like that

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_donations">
```

The question is how to make the html form lead to the **Enhanced** Paypal Checkout page, which is more modern and functional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, donations and subscriptions do not have an 'enhanced checkout page'.

Only Buy Now, Add to Cart, _Cart Upload, and Express Checkout payments use the 'enhanced checkout page'.

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news. However, you can easily change the image of a buy now button to use the image of a donation button, and just direct them to the buy now page that uses the 'enhanced checkout pages'.*

*Keep in mind that your checkout page will now be worded as a purchase (as it's PayPal's buy now page)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't care for the wording, but mostly I care if paypal will keep more commission in case of an order instead of donation page. I think that if you prove that you are non-profit, they charge less. Isn't it so?

Comment: Is it possible through the API (and not with html forms) to have enhanced checkout for donations?

Comment: @john, Donations are charged the same fees as all other wps transactions. Also, you could use Express Checkout charge the customer (same fee) but it would be more work than it's worth. Buy now buttons would do the same thing, with a lot less work.

Comment: what is express checkout charge?